# How to import excel data into sqlite database in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have data in multiple excel files,  I have to import excel specific sheet data into an SQLite database using python.

I prepared these excel files every week so once the table is created into SQLite database and one week file is imported then every week I have to append excel file.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to read Excel(.xlsx) files. Then you can use [Sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module to write the data into the sqlite3 database.

openpyxl is a third party module, so you have to use pip to install it.

> pip install openpyxl

sqlite3 module is built in the default python modules, so you don't need to pip for it.

There are tons of examples on how to use openxl on its web page. You'll find the way how to read the data in your Excel files.

Answer (score 4):

I have simply written below code into the juypitor notebook and it imports my excel data into sqlite3 database. working fine.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect('cps.db')
wb = pd.read_excel('CPS\CPS.xlsx',sheet_name = None)

for sheet in wb:
    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet,con,index=False)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not preserve images (blobs).

Comment: For me this writes each column in the Excel table into a separate SQLite table, so if the Excel table has 10 columns you get 10 separate SQLite tables. I don't think that is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the sheet to a single table.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

cxn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
wb = pd.read_excel('myxl.xlsx',sheet_name = 'mysheet')
wb.to_sql(name='mytable',con=cxn,if_exists='replace',index=True)
cxn.commit()
cxn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would probably be to export your Excel files to CSV files, and use the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read this data in your Python program.

You can then use the [sqlite module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) to write this data in your database.